# What in .htaccess can block cron

Tags: .htaccess, magento, cron

I'm making my own shop with Magento, and I'm not really comfortable with programation, even if I know some basics. I'm running CE 1.9.3.1 with SUPEE 9652 patch.
I set up my .htaccess with

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from 123.45.678.90 (example IP server Address)
Deny from all
```

However, the cron is still blocked by .htaccess, as when I remove (or rename) .htaccess, it's running (white page with mydomain/cron.php). My cron is set from my hosting pannel with Cronjob, but displaying a 403 error with my .htaccess.

Can someone point me what else could be blocking the cron in my .htaccess?

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

    ############################################
    ## adjust memory limit

    #    #php_value memory_limit 64M
    #php_value memory_limit 256M
    #php_value max_execution_time 18000

    ############################################
    ## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    #php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

    ############################################
    ## disable automatic session start
    ## before autoload was initialized

    #php_flag session.auto_start off

    ############################################
    ## enable resulting html compression

    ##php_flag zlib.output_compression on

    ###########################################
    # disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    #php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

    ###########################################
    # turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    #php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    ###########################################
    # disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    ############################################
    ## enable apache served files compression
    ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    ############################################
    ## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    ############################################
    ## enable rewrites

    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine on

    ############################################
    ## you can put here your magento root folder
    ## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

    ############################################
    ## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

    #    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

    ############################################
    ## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

    ############################################
    ## workaround for HTTP authorization
    ## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    ############################################
    ## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks



    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>

            ############################################
            # X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff disable content-type sniffing on some browsers.
            Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

            ############################################
            # This header forces to enables the Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter in browsers (if disabled)
            BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s8 ie8
            Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block" env=!ie8

        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    ############################################
    ## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

    ############################################
    ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

    ############################################
    ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    ############################################
    ## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ############################################
    ## Add default Expires header
    ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

# Order allow,deny
# Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

#FileETag none

###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php
<Files cron.php>

    ############################################
    ## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
    ## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
    ##
    ## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
    ## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
    ## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.

    AuthName "Cron auth"
    AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
    AuthType basic
    Require valid-user

    ############################################

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 123.45.678.90 (example IP server Address)
    Deny from all


</Files>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You also have HTTP Authentication enabled - presumably you are passing the appropriate credentials?

Comment: I guess it should't be the case, as I'm using SSL certif on the site. I tried to comment this line:    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] But it didn't helped...

Comment: @w3dk Any other line/code I should add/comment to run cron?

Comment: How is the cron job being called? I was really referring to the `Require valid-user` (and associated) directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out... it was a mistake from my part.
I commented lines

```
AuthName "Cron auth"
AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
AuthType basic
Require valid-user
```

as they deserve to protect the code with a password. Someone from my hosting provider had suggested me to uncomment them (!)

But the main matter was coming from

```
<Files cron.php>
```

as my Magento install is in a folder, I had to  modify it as following:

```
<Files folder/cron.php>
```

The server logs errors helped me to understand it...